# Dovecot error: ssl enabled, but ssl_cert not set

Tags: ssl-certificate, dovecot, openssl

I've been trying to get Postfix and Dovecot set up for days and I think I have resolved all problems except for one that just came up. When I try to restart Dovecot I get the following error message:

```
doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf: ssl enabled, but  
ssl_cert not set
[....] Restarting IMAP/POP3 mail server: dovecotdoveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration 
file /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf: ssl enabled, but ssl_cert not set
```

When I check dovecot.conf, there is nothing regarding ssl so I assume the error is referencing the settings in `10-ssl.conf`. I noticed that the settings are commented out:

```
# ssl = no
# ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/dovecot.pem
# ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
```

I know these were uncommented earlier but if I uncomment now, I get a different error at startup about unexpected value ssl in 10-ssl.conf. From the Dovecot wiki this value must be set even if it is overwritten by a specific protocol elsewhere.

If I leave the ssl values commented out I get the first error message about ssl being enabled but not set.

Earlier I had created a self-signed certificate using OpenSSL and was not receiving any error messages about ssl not being configured. In fact, I was able to login to pops from another client machine and it gave the usual warning about the certificate being untrusted.
I did notice however that the cert referenced an incorrect hostname and this was caused earlier after I rebuilt my VPS and foolishly installed and configured Dovecot with incorrect hostname being set.

Well I purged all files and reinstalled. I have again deleted all keys and regenerated with OpenSSL a couple times but now I cannot even start Dovecot because of this error. I'm stuck and was wondering how I should approach this. Is it possible that something in Postfix referencing Dovecot is causing this?

Some sites say to check your syntax such as `ssl_cert = </etc` vs `ssl_cert = /etc` but this has not made a difference. I would also be happy to just temporarily disable ssl to get around the error, but that fails as well.

Just now I tried to create a symbolic link to the prebuilt keys in `/etc/dovecot` and `/etc/dovecot.pem` but I get the same message.

Comment: Also, why would it say SSL is enabled if it has not been set in 10-ssl.conf or dovecot.conf? Where is it being enabled? I checked Postfix but main.cf only points to the certs. Could it be something in /etc/postfix/master.cf? I checked but didn't notice anything.

Comment: Run `grep ssl /etc/dovecot/* -R` to see, where ssl is mentioned in config files.

Answer (score 5):

Old post however:The error comes from the fact that the main configuration file dovecot.conf needs to have a line: "!include conf.d/*.conf"
at the end.

Otherwise it won't load the configuration files that you have inside "conf.d/"

I think this is the reason why you are not getting any difference from changing the settings in the config files within "conf.d/"

> Also, why would it say SSL is enabled if it has not been set in 10-ssl.conf or dovecot.conf? Where is it being enabled?

That's because the default configuration is ssl = yes. Not having included the 10-ssl.conf file, where you could either deactivate ssl or set the cert file gives you that result.

Answer (score 1):

My Dovecot configuration in `dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf`, which is working on two different servers, is:

```
ssl = yes
ssl_cert = </path/to/cert.file
ssl_key = </path/to/key.file
```

I use a certificate authority, so I also have:

```
ssl_ca = </path/to/ca-bundle.pem
```

It has been some time since I set the servers up, but I do recall having issues with Dovecot, and I believe they were separate from Postfix.

I'm not sure about the unexpected value error. When you uncommented, did you change `ssl = no` to `ssl = yes`? I also know that OpenSSL is a little picky about file permissions. My key file is owned by root:root and has 400 permissions set.

Comment: I had changed it from ssl = yes to ssl = no and then when I tried to change it back to yes the trouble started.

Comment: Could you show output of the # dovecot -n ?

Comment: I think I can do better. Here is the page I used as a guide to set my mail servers up:

https://www.exratione.com/2012/05/a-mailserver-on-ubuntu-1204-postfix-dovecot-mysql/

Comment: The key file needs to be readable by Dovecot. If you have an sslcerts group make it group readable using that group and add the dovecot user to that group.  Also the command `dovecot -n` will output the full configuration after inclusions.   This can be helpful for debugging.

Comment: There are changes to Dovecot in the latest release.  I needed to update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Check 20-imap.conf (http://wiki2.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration):

```
protocol imap {
  ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/dovecot.pem
  ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
}
```

and 10-ssl.conf:
`ssl_parameters_regenerate = 0` <<-- default 168 hours

Upd:

```
doveconf -a | grep ssl
```